# How can I get hold of the "Note" from a google calendar event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a spreadsheet with a list of tasks that I assign to members of my team. I have a bound google app script that creates events in the assignees calendars, and another that syncs changes to schedule and gueststatus back to the spreadsheet. Both scripts works well enough.

My question is this:
In the sync back to the spreadsheet, I would also like to include any text written in the "Add Note" (Button behind the up-arrow at the bottom left corner of the event when clicked from the calendar (next to "Yes", "No", "Maybe")). I have searched around for many hours now, but cannot find anything at all about this.

Does anyone know if/how this can be coded?

I am new to google app scripts (and coding in general for that matter) so I will be greatful for any advice that might guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

This data isn't available to the basic Calendar App service. You can instead use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).

Note that you have to enable this service before you use it. To do so, click the + next to Services, and add the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference).

The attendee note is available as `event.attendees[].comment`. Check the [Event Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events).

### Example:

```
var event = Calendar.Events.get(user, eventId);
var attendees = event.attendees;
if (attendees) {
  event.attendees.forEach(_ => Logger.log(`${_.email}, ${_.comment}`));
}
```

### Reference:

- [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)
- [Event Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)
- [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference)